# How to delete from firebase realtime database，

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

[image]

I want to delete apple in breakfast separately, but the above method will delete all apples, regardless of whether it is breakfast, lunch, or dinner. Is there any solution? Thank you

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was so helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add this second condition to the query, as Firebase Realtime Database can only query on one property. See [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

If you want to only delete a subset of the items returned by the query, you'll have to check for the addition condition in your loop:

```
for (DataSnapshot data: snapshot.getChildren()) {
  if ("apple".equals(data.child("foodname").getValue(String.class))) {
    data.getRef().removeValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was so helpful to me